# С# WPF Работа с реестром через WMI

Tags: c#, консоль, wmi

Необходимо получить список всех установленных приложений на удаленном компьютере. Класс WMI Win32_Pdoduct показывает только программы установленные с помощью Microsoft Installer. Для того чтобы увидеть все программы необходимо лезть в реестр (Класс StdRegProv). Подскажите как в C# с помощью WMI получить информацию из ключа реестра HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: [How to Read Remote Registry Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1566547/312041)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/04/Read-Registry-Value-using-WMI-in-CSharp.html

```
private static List<string> ReadRegistryusingWMI()
    {
        List<string> programs = new List<string>();

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Connect();

        string softwareRegLoc = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

        ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("EnumKey");
        inParams["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002;//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
        inParams["sSubKeyName"] = softwareRegLoc;

        // Read Registry Key Names 
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("EnumKey", inParams, null);
        string[] programGuids = outParams["sNames"] as string[];

        foreach (string subKeyName in programGuids)
        {
            inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
            inParams["sSubKeyName"] = softwareRegLoc + @"\" + subKeyName;
            inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName";
            // Read Registry Value 
            outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
            if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
            {
                string softwareName = outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();
                programs.Add(softwareName);
            }
        }

        return programs;
    }

    //HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (2147483648 (0x80000000))
    //HKEY_CURRENT_USER (2147483649 (0x80000001))
    //HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (2147483650 (0x80000002))
    //HKEY_USERS (2147483651 (0x80000003))
    //HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG (2147483653 (0x80000005))
```